# NextJS Server Action Classes?

Tags: next.js, react-server-components, server-action

I love building services in an OOP fashion with classes to keep related interactions altogether.

I want to have my entire class and its methods be used as Server Actions to interact with my DB in a NextJS Application.

Any thoughts on how to get that done, or is the 'use server' directive covers it for the file??

```
import { CollectionService } from "./collectionsService";

export interface resumeType {
  id?: string;
  image_url: string;
  download: string;
  view: string;
  categories: string[];
}

class resumeCollectionService extends CollectionService<resumeType> {
  constructor() {
    super('resumes');
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to instantiate a class that preserves its state between multiple Server Action calls?